# javascript as target in kotlin multiplatform library

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I'm building a Kotlin multiplatform library. One of the targets in this project is javascript. In the source set I have added a dependency like this:

```
 val jsMain by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation(npm("libphonenumber-js", "1.10.13"))
        }
    }
```

The gradle sync was successful, now I want to import the files in jsMain directory. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to know how to use JS code form Kotlin? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-interop.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add npm dependency with `generateExternals` as you already did
  `implementation(npm("libphonenumber-js", "1.10.13", generateExternals = true))`
- `generateExternals = true` triggers a tool called [Dukat](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-external-declarations-with-dukat.html) that generates Kotlin external declarations from the Typescript definition file of that `npm` module.
- Once your project syncs, it would have `externals` folder under your shared module's `build` folder like shown below,

[image: Screenshot of how external generated Kotlin code folder structure looks like]

(Ignore `kmp-lib-1621` in above image. That would be your module/library name instead)`

- Now copy and paste these files in your project (`jsMain` source set) and remove `generateExternal = true` from your dependency otherwise it would generate this files everytime. (1) you would lose any manual change (2) if you update the library version then it can potentially break your project

You should be able to call generated external code from `Kotlin` code, whether you keep it in `build` folder or you `pasted` it in your project code.

> Important Note: `Dukat` tool is experiemental and known to create externals that may not work 100% times. So remove all unnecessary code from external generated code so you only end up having few references of classes you want to use from the `npm` library. Do some trial and error and you would be fine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Shaktiman. What would be the right way to import the files. As far as I can see in the generated files, there are a bunch of external functions. So, in my kotlin file I'm importing like

`import isPossibleNumber as possibleNumber
import isValidNumberForRegion as validNumberForRegion`

is there any better way to import?

Comment: Once you've external generated code, it's just normal `Kotlin` code, so you can use it how you would normally import a Kotlin reference. If you're new to Kotlin, then this document may help with understanding imports. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/packages.html

Comment: for the below dependency, the external files are not getting generated. What could be the reason?

`implementation(npm("google-libphonenumber", "3.2.30", generateExternals = true))`

Comment: @AnmolSinghSahi because that library doesn't have `Typescript` definition. Dukat needs `Typescript` definition to generate externals. That said, `DefinitelyTyped` repo has support for that package. Use this package instead to generate externals https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google-libphonenumber. Keep original npm dependency as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `js(IR)` backend and generate externals
`implementation(npm("libphonenumber-js", "1.10.13", generateExternals = true))`.

Comment: I have added this. Now, how to import the library in the kotlin class inside jsMain? For example for ios we have use like
`import cocoapods.libPhoneNumber_iOS.*`

Comment: You can just use it e.g. `findNumbers("")`.